# following code showing segmentation fault

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

why the following code shows segmentation fault?

```
int CreateRawSocket(int protocol_to_sniff)
{
    int rawsock;

    if((rawsock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(protocol_to_sniff)))== -1)
    {
        perror("Error creating raw socket: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return rawsock;
}

int BindRawSocketToInterface(char *device, int rawsock, int protocol)
{

    struct sockaddr_ll sll;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    bzero(&sll, sizeof(sll));
     bzero(&ifr,sizeof(ifr));

    /* First Get the Interface Index  */

         char *t=(char*)ifr.ifr_name;
    strncpy(t, device, 1024);
    if((ioctl(rawsock, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error getting Interface index !\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* Bind our raw socket to this interface */

    sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sll.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    sll.sll_protocol = htons(protocol); 


    if((bind(rawsock, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(sll)))== -1)
    {
        perror("Error binding raw socket to interface\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 1;

}

void PrintPacketInHex(unsigned char *packet, int len)
{
    unsigned char *p = packet;

    printf("\n\n---------Packet---Starts----\n\n");

    while(len--)
    {
        printf("%.2x ", *p);
        p++;
    }

    printf("\n\n--------Packet---Ends-----\n\n");

}


main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int raw;
    unsigned char packet_buffer[2048]; 
    int len;
    int packets_to_sniff;
    struct sockaddr_ll packet_info;
    int packet_info_size = sizeof(packet_info);

    /* create the raw socket */

    raw = CreateRawSocket(ETH_P_IP);

    /* Bind socket to interface */

    BindRawSocketToInterface(argv[1], raw, ETH_P_IP);

    /* Get number of packets to sniff from user */

    packets_to_sniff = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* Start Sniffing and print Hex of every packet */

    while(packets_to_sniff--)
    {
        if((len = recvfrom(raw, packet_buffer, 2048, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&packet_info, &packet_info_size)) == -1)
        {
            perror("Recv from returned -1: ");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            /* Packet has been received successfully !! */

            PrintPacketInHex(packet_buffer, len);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does it crash?  On what address does it crash?  What are the sizes of the buffers?

Comment: I refuse to even look at this. Do some debugging and narrow it down. You're obviously not new to programming, or you wouldn't be writing programs of this complexity. Once you've narrowed it down to the specific module and line that crashes, post back.

Comment: Argh my eyes. Too much whitespace!!

Comment: You could always run it in valgrind, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is caused by this line in your routine BindRawSocketToInterface:

```
strncpy(t, device, 1024);
```

Here you've asked `strncpy` to write 1024 bytes into `char *t`.   **Note that `strncpy` pads the destination string with the specified number of null bytes**, see *man strncpy*).

But `t` points to an array which isn't nearly large enough, namely `ifr.ifr_name[IFNAMSIZ]`.  On my linux system, `IFNAMSIZ` is only 16.  So `strncpy` overflows and trashes memory that it shouldn't be touching.

Changing the `strncpy` parameter to match the correct size of the array as follows fixes the crash:

```
strncpy(t, device, IFNAMSIZ);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a memory violation when you do not give enough command line arguments as you do not check argc.